# Why occur animation effect in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var randColor: Color {
        Color(red: randomNumber/255, green: randomNumber/255, blue: randomNumber/255)
    }
    @State var isAnimation = false
    
    var randomNumber: Double {
        return Double.random(in: 0...255)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(isAnimation ? randColor : .red)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .onAppear {
                    withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true)) {
                        isAnimation = true
                    }
                }
            
            BottomRectangle()
            
        }
    }
}

struct bottomRectangle: View {
    
    var randomNumber: Double {
        return Double.random(in: 0...255)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color(red: randomNumber/255,
                          green: randomNumber/255,
                          blue: randomNumber/255))
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```

In the code above, bottomRectangle() does not change color and has no animation effect.

[image]

but, Adding the following to the code creates an animation effect that continuously changes the color of the Bottom Rectangle.
I don't understand why Bottom Rectangle has an animation effect.

1. add `@State var a = false`
2. change to `a ? Color.blue : Color(red: randomNumber/255, green: randomNumber/255, blue: randomNumber/255)` in Rectangle

```
struct BottomRectangle: View {
    
    @State var a = false
    
    var randomNumber: Double {
        return Double.random(in: 0...255)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(a ?
                  Color.blue :
                    Color(red: randomNumber/255,
                          green: randomNumber/255,
                          blue: randomNumber/255))
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```

[image]

**HELP ME!!!**

Comment: I copied the code for `ContentView`, and the second `BottomRectangle` into a new project, but I cannot reproduce. Did you forget something in your [mcve]?

Comment: @Sweeper This is all the code. But now that I've tested it, the results change every time I compile. Sometimes the animation works and sometimes it doesn't. Why is this happening..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the state that changes the color in `BottomRectangle` is getting updated because SwiftUI is redrawing the entire view in `ContentView` and `a` is getting reinitialized as a result. This then triggers the initial instance of the setting the color for the `.fill`. Because this is random, you see this occurring. The solution is to have the state held outside of the `BottomRectangle` view. Something as simple as this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var a = false // Hold the state in the parent view, or a ViewModel

    var randColor: Color {
        Color(red: randomNumber/255, green: randomNumber/255, blue: randomNumber/255)
    }
    @State var isAnimation = false
    
    var randomNumber: Double {
        return Double.random(in: 0...255)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(isAnimation ? randColor : .red)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .onAppear {
                    withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true)) {
                        isAnimation = true
                    }
                }
            
            BottomRectangle(a: $a)
            
        }
    }
}

struct BottomRectangle: View {
    
    @Binding var a: Bool
    
    var randomNumber: Double {
        return Double.random(in: 0...255)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(a ?
                  Color.blue :
                    Color(red: randomNumber/255,
                          green: randomNumber/255,
                          blue: randomNumber/255))
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```